# Let $X$ be a topological space and $U$ be aproper dense open subset of $X$. Pick the correct statement from the following

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $U$ be a proper dense open subset of $X$. Pick the correct statement from the following

(A) If $X$ is connected then $U$ is connected.

(B) If $X$ is compact then $U$ is compact.

(C)If $X\setminus U$ is compact the $X$ is compact.

(D)If $X$ is compact, then $X\setminus U$ is compact.

My attempt:-

(A) The usual topology on $\mathbb R$ and $U=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb Z}(n,n+1)$ is open as well as dense. But not connected.

(B) Let $X=[0,1]$ and $U=(0,1)\cap \mathbb Q$. $U$ is open aswell as dense. But not compact.

(D)If $X$ is compact. suppose $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \Lambda}$ be an open cover for $X\setminus U$. Then,$\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \Lambda}\bigcup \{U\} $covers $X.$ So, It must have finite subcover. Hence the result follows.

(C)This is my attempt to create counterexample for $(C)$. Suppose $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \Lambda}$ be an open cover for $X$. We know that $x\in U,\implies \exists \alpha \in \Lambda: x\in U_\alpha$. If $U$ is finite, the result follows. But here $U$ is arbitrary. How do I cook counterexample from here?

Comment: Would $X=(0,1]$, $U=(0,1)$ work?

Comment: For (B), $(0,1) \cap \mathbb Q$ is not open in $[0,1]$. But $(0,1)$ works as a counterexample

Comment: @DavidMitra I think your example is fine.

Comment: @YuiToCheng Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), your counterexample works.

For (b), $X=[0,1]$ with $U=(0,1)$ works as a counterexample.

For (c), $X=[0,1)$ with $U=(0,1)$ works again.

For (d),  the statement is correct as $X-U$ is a closed subset of $X$, hence compact.

Comment: Here in $(c)$ we have $X = [0,1]$ compact, so this does not yield a counterexample.

Comment: @GuidoA. Sorry for the sloppiness.

Answer (score 2):

For $(b)$, as said in the comments $U$ should be open, so you can instead choose $U = (0,1)$. As for $(c)$, you can consider $[0,1)$ with $U = (0,1)$ once again. The space $X \setminus U = \{0\}$ is certainly compact, but $X$ is not.